# session does not work with mod-rewrited urls?

Tags: php, session, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this page www.exmaple.com/username which is rewritten url, but the sessions does not work there.

That is, when I echo, it does not show the value, but all the other pages that have not been re-written are working!

```
<?php session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user_id'];

?>
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Does this rewrite involve a change of domain or subdomain in the URL? Cookies are, by default, accessible only to the same subdomain they were set on... and session identifiers are maintained by cookies.

Comment: no same domain name, i dnt have any subdomains yet!!

Comment: Oh but good point by @Dan Grossman: Do your cookies set a path? Remember that a mod_rewritten URL like the one you show can be interpreted as a different directory by the browser

Comment: actually i kind of found the problem, when i go to `http://example.com/solomon` it deosnt work, but if i go to `http://www.example.com/solomon` it works!!! thats wierd!!!

Comment: Those are different subdomains - www is a subdomain. A session started on one won't be continued on the other by default because the session cookie won't be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this rewrite involve a change of domain or subdomain in the URL? Cookies are, by default, accessible only to the same subdomain they were set on... and session identifiers are maintained by cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are not affected by mod_rewrite, but you need to prepend every page with `session_start()`.

Comment: sorry i i do have that at the beginning i forget to mention!!

Comment: @getaway okay. I'm still fairly sure it has nothing to do with mod_rewrite!

Comment: oh okay :)) im confused myself

Answer (score 0):

You must call `session_start()` to read the session or `$_SESSION` will not be populated.

Comment: sorry i i do have that at the beginning i forget to mention!!